# having issues while clicking on a dropdown window with edit or delete button inside the dropdown

Tags: automated-tests, click, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

compare 1 with 2 & 1 with 3, can click edit when I exclude await from expect or when I do await t.expect with await

## 1.

```js
await t.expect(DetailsPage.commentsBody.find(`.dropdown-menu.show`).exists).ok(`comments drop down menu unavailable`)
       .click(DetailsPage.edit) //  ***----- doesn't clicks and throws error***  
       .expect(await DetailsPage.addCommentWindow.value).eql(comData.comment);
```

## 2.

```js
await t.expect(DetailsPage.commentsBody.find(`.dropdown-menu.show`).exists).ok(`comments drop down menu unavailable`)
       .click(DetailsPage.edit)  // **----- does click and no error**
       .expect(DetailsPage.addCommentWindow.value).eql(comData.comment);
```

## 3.

```js
await t.expect(DetailsPage.commentsBody.find(`.dropdown-menu.show`).exists).ok(`comments drop down menu unavailable`)
       .click(DetailsPage.edit);  // **----- does click and no error**

await t.expect(await DetailsPage.addCommentWindow.value).eql(comData.comment);
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 is the right one. You should never use `await` in `expect`. TestCafe awaits selector promises and does it at the right moment of the time and during the specified timeout. Option 1 doesn't work because you forced the `DetailsPage.addCommentWindow.value` evaluation before `DetailsPage.edit` is clicked.